# get usergroup of user in vbulletin using java and htmlunit

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit, vbulletin

I am working on a login system that checks if the user is in a spesific usergroup.

If the user is in the usergroup "Access" then i want to show them the next form. If they are in the usergroup "registered user" it will display "Sorry, you dont have access"

This is my code so far: This will log in with 2 textboxes shown on a form.

I know i should not call "gettext();" on password field but i dont know how to code it so the htmlunit understands the characters and not puts in chars of array if i write "getpassword()"

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package testmysql.gui;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

/**
 *
 * @author Kjetil
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public String setuser;
    public String setpass;
    public char[] input;
    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtboxPass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        txtboxUser = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 70, -1, -1));

        txtboxPass.setText("jPasswordField1");
        getContentPane().add(txtboxPass, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 40, -1, -1));

        txtboxUser.setText("jTextField1");
        getContentPane().add(txtboxUser, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 10, 110, -1));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


         setuser = txtboxUser.getText();
         setpass = txtboxPass.getText();

         Login();

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtboxPass;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtboxUser;
    // End of variables declaration                   





private void Login()
{



        try {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); // I think this speeds the thing up
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

            String url = "http://svergja.com/forum";
            String name = setuser;
            String pass = setpass;

            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

            System.out.println(
                    "1st page : " + page.asText());

            HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementById("navbar_loginform");
            HtmlInput uName = (HtmlInput) form.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"navbar_username\"]").get(0);

            uName.setValueAttribute(name);
            HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) form.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"navbar_password\"]").get(0);

            password.setValueAttribute(setpass);
            HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Log in"); 
            //(HtmlSubmitInput) form.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"loginbutton\"]").get(0);

            WebWindow window = page.getEnclosingWindow();
            button.click();


            while (window.getEnclosedPage() == page) {
                // The page hasn't changed.
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
// This loop above will wait until the page changes.
            page = (HtmlPage) window.getEnclosedPage();

            System.out.println(
                    "2nd Page : " + page.asText());

            webClient.closeAllWindows();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }



}


}
```

If the login is successful i want to start checking for the usergroup ID of the user. If i log in, my usergroup is Administrator. I will add a test user so you can log in and see for yourself.

(log in with this "you will be in the usergroup ("Registered Users")")

### Forum url: http://svergja.com/forum

Username: stackoverflow

### Password: stackit123

(test user information)

Comment: @Niks Tyagi I am very new to html and htmlunit. I dont know what to look for. Can i get the usergroup right after the login or do i have to go into "my profil" and then search for the text usergroup? 

Also if you have a fix for how to use "getPassword()" from passwordField that would be great ; )

I just dont know what i am supposed to type to get htmlunit to get the text of the usergroup that the user is in.

Comment: I login with provided credential but cant found from where to find the usergroup.Can you provide me exact path to find it.Thn i can help u in html unit

Comment: @Niks Tyagi Log in with chrome or whatever then click on stackoverflow right next to welcome, or you can click on "my profile" that will take you to your profile and under your name you will see usergroup = "Registered Users"

Comment: damn it, users can't see it. I can use the usertitle instead. I can just set custom title to everyone that will have access. The user title will be in the same place but will say "Junior Member" instead

Comment: yes i found junior Member.You want to scrap this ?? Also which htmlunit version u r using ?

Comment: i am using 2.14-OSG Is that good?

Yeah I just need to verify the "user title" with a if statement.

if (usergroup == "junior member")
grant access
else
sorry you dont have access will be displayed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48102/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-user3258301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the successfull login, use anchor to click profile link and then use span to get the usergroup.
The change in code will be:

```
   private void Login() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://svergja.com/forum/");

            HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementById("navbar_loginform");

            HtmlTextInput username = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("navbar_username");
                username.setValueAttribute("stackoverflow");
            HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getElementById("navbar_password");
                password.setValueAttribute("stackit123");
            HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Log in"); 
            page = button.click();

            List<HtmlAnchor> anchorList = page.getAnchors();
                for (HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor : anchorList) {
                    if(htmlAnchor.getAttribute("href").contains("member.php?"))
                    {
                        page = htmlAnchor.click();
                    }
                }

                HtmlSpan span = (HtmlSpan) page.getElementById("userinfo");
                DomNodeList<DomNode> nodeList = span.getChildNodes();

                    for (DomNode domNode : nodeList) {

                        NamedNodeMap map = domNode.getAttributes();
                        Node node = map.getNamedItem("class");
                          if(node != null && node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue().equals("usertitle"))
                          {
                                System.out.println("The usergroup is "+domNode.getTextContent());
                          }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: It goes directly to stackoverflow's "profile" not the user logged in.

If i change the username to svergja and password it still goes to stackoverflow's "profile".

Comment: It works kind of now, I just changed the contains to the Username the user will put in instead of member.php? beceause it took the member.php? link that was the newest member to the forum.

The only problem now is that it is Case sensitiv and the Username MUST match a 100% for it to work. So users will have to write their username with upper and lower cases for the function to work.

Comment: so ur issue is fixed or still facing some pblm ?

Comment: Well, the user has to write their username EXACT as it is because of if(htmlAnchor.getAttribute("href").contains("setUser"))

setUser = string wich equals the text put into the username textbox.

So if I am going to login I have to write: Svergja (svergja will not work) because it is case sensitive.

and if i use if(htmlAnchor.getAttribute("href").contains("member.php?"))

It goes to the profile of the newest member to the forum
                    {

Comment: i have put member.php? as href contains check so it will change ??

Comment: Yes, the member.php? goes to the newest member of the forum bebacuse of a link on the page has it. And it comes before the "my profile". So it will always go to the newest member if i use member.php?. Thats why i changed it to check if the link contains the username of the user who is trying to log in. and thats why i have the problem with case sensitive characters ; )

Comment: sry i cant understand the issue.

Comment: When I use your code it brings up stackoverflow's Usertitle because he is the last member that registered on the forum. If i register another user and try to use your code again it will go to the new users profile. Because it goes to the newest member of the forum because it is a link togheter with the "My Profile" link and it doesn't click on "My Profile" it clicks on the the link with "welcome to our newest member - USERNAMEHERE". Do you understand now? If you go the website you will see that it says welcome to our newest member stackoverflow. almost at the bottom of the page.